# IdentityServer4/JWT: Manually parsing JWT token to user

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm issuing a JWT token and want to validate it manually (the original JWT token was issued by the webapi during authentication and is working fine there. So my guess, I'm doing something wrong during my validation?

```
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken validatedToken;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new();
        var user = handler.ValidateToken(authStr, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

which looks quite trivial, validation parameters are the same used for the initial generation.

When calling the ValidateToken method, an exception gets thrown:

```
IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.\nAlgorithm: 'RS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: ''.'\n is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms\r\n
```

which is a quite obvious error, as validation parameters are generated like that:

```
       var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
       {
           ValidIssuer = Configuration["IdentityServer:TokenValidationParameters:ValidIssuer"],
           ValidAudiences = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiences").Get<List<string>>(),
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["IdentityServer:TokenValidationParameters:Secret"])),
           NameClaimType = Configuration["IdentityServer:TokenValidationParameters:NameClaimType"],
           RoleClaimType = Configuration["IdentityServer:TokenValidationParameters:RoleClaimType"],
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
       };
```

that means basically I've to replace the call SymmetricSecurityKey(..) with something else, but unfortunately I was not figure out with which function/type?
Could someone advise?